# Trigger Azure YAML Pipeline with Tags

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, tags, azure-pipelines-yaml

Trying to trigger an Azure YAML pipeline using **Tag** when another YAML pipeline has been completed.
There's [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/pipeline-triggers?view=azure-devops#tag-filters) indicating that you can add a pipeline resource with:

```
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: MyCIAlias
    source: Farbrikam-CI
    trigger:
      tags:        # This filter is used for triggering the pipeline run
      - Production # Tags are AND'ed
      - Signed
```

This is my code which I am adding in my 2nd pipeline which I want to trigger using tag automatically:

```
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: POCPipeline
    source: \***\***
    trigger:
      tags:
      - Tagtest
```

Can someone please help me with this if anything is wrong as it is not triggering my 2nd pipeline with **Tagtest**?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your `source pipeline` with the tag?

Comment: I am triggering my 1st Pipeline and giving the tag at runtime. Do you want that screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, your sample works fine. The pipelines:

[image]

The trigger for the second pipeline:

```
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: MyCIAlias
    source: \MyNewPipelines\MySourceTriggerPipline
    trigger:
      tags:        # This filter is used for triggering the pipeline run
      - Tagtest
```

If you add the tag to the source build during the build process, the second pipeline starts fine:

[image]

You may add the tag manually or through the logging command: [AddBuildTag: Add a tag to the build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#addbuildtag-add-a-tag-to-the-build)

Example for the first pipeline to add a tag through variables and logging command:

```
- task: Bash@3
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      echo "##vso[build.addbuildtag]$(tagtoadd)"
```

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce the same issue that the **Tag filters** for pipeline resource does not work with below configurations. The current pipeline cannot be triggered by the pipeline resource completed on tage '**`tag01`**'.

```yaml
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: resPipe1
    source: resPipe1-CI
    trigger:
      tags:
      - tag01
```

or

```yaml
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: resPipe1
    source: resPipe1-CI
    trigger:
      tags:
      - refs/tags/tag01
```

---

When I change the configuration of pipeline resource like as below, the current pipeline can be triggered by the pipeline resource.

```yaml
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: resPipe1
    source: resPipe1-CI
    trigger: true
```

However, this configuration will let the current pipeline be triggered when the pipeline resource runs is completed on any branch or any tag.

---

Looks like, there is problem on the **Tag filters** for pipeline resource. I recommend you try open a ticket on [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/AzureDevOps/report) to report this issue. If the support engineer who handles your ticket also can reproduce the same issue, your ticket generally will be reported to the appropriate product team for further investigation and fix.

---